# Apex Web Services Trailhead: Need 100% Code Coverage

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I can't seem to figure out how to reach 100% code coverage. Currently, I'm at 80% and the "return acct;" is the only thing that is not covered. Could somebody help me figure out how to test this?
The error/fail in debug is:
"System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject"
and the Stack Trace is:
"Class.AccountManager.getAccount: line 10, column 1
Class.AccountManagerTest.testGetAccount: line 11, column 1"

ACCOUNT MANAGER CLASS:

```
@RestResource (urlMapping = '/Account/*/contacts')
global with sharing class AccountManager
{
    @HttpGet
    global static Account getAccount ()
    {
        RestRequest request = RestContext.request;
        String accountId = request.requestURI.substring(request.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        //Account acct =  [SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountId];
        Account acct = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountId];
        return acct;
    }
}
```

ACCOUNT MANAGER TEST:

```
@isTest
private class AccountManagerTest
{
    @isTest static void testGetAccount ()
    {
        Id recordId = createTestRecord ();
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest ();
        request.requestUri = 'https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Accounts/' + recordId + '/contacts';
        request.httpMethod = 'GET';
        RestContext.request = request;
        Account thisAccount = AccountManager.getAccount();
        System.assert (thisAccount != null);
        System.assertEquals ('Test Record', thisAccount.Name);

    }

    static Id createTestRecord ()
    {
        Account testAccount = new Account (Name = 'Test Record');
        insert testAccount;
        Contact testContact = new Contact (AccountId = testAccount.Id);
        return testAccount.Id;
    }

}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks for the Id thus:

```
String accountId = request.requestURI.substring(request.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

You set the URI thus:

```
'https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Accounts/' + recordId + '/contacts'
```

So your code is filtering:

```
WHERE Id = 'contacts'
```

Change your URI to remove `+ '/contacts'`.

Comment: Okay, thank you. That makes sense: I'm asking for whatever comes after the last "/", and in this case it is "contacts" so I am basically saying accountId = "contacts". When I removed that last bit of code I did achieve 100% coverage. However, when I tried to check the challenge it said that "There was an unexpected error in your org which is preventing this assessment check from completing: System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject". After looking around I realized that this could be because the query is coming back empty. Why?

Answer (score 1):

You should leave the URI as

```
`.....apexrest/Accounts/' + recordId + '/contacts'
```

but extract the account recordId like this:

```
String accountId = request.requestURI.substringBetween('Accounts/', '/contacts');
```

Kudos to Lei Shi at https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000MIs9IAG